# Trouble installing Ruby gem for ZeroMq on windows

Tags: ruby, windows, zeromq

I am trying to create a simple Ruby app on Windows that uses ZeroMq, but i am having trouble installing the ruby gem 'zmq'

So how do i install the ZeroMq gem 'zmq' on windows. I get an error when i try with the command:

```
gem install zmq -- --with-zmq-dir=C:/utils/ZeroMQ2.2.0 --with-zmq-lib=C:/utils/ZeroMQ2.2.0/include
```

i get this error:

```
c:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb --with-zmq-dir=C:/utils/ZeroMQ2.2.0 --with-zmq-lib=C:/utils/ZeroMQ2.2.0/include
checking for zmq.h... yes
checking for zmq_init() in -lzmq... no
checking for zmq_init() in -lzmq... no
extconf.rb:36:in `<main>': Couldn't find zmq library. try setting --with-zmq-dir=<path> to tell me where it is. (RuntimeError)
```

Here's my ZeroMq Folder

```
C:\utils\ZeroMQ2.2.0>
+---bin
+---doc
+---include
+---lib
\---src
```

Comment: You will run into a million more issues when using Ruby + Rails + Windows. Switch to Linux for Ruby development, or you are in for a world of hurt.